# Why my app is not displaying decimal points even know i am using float value

Tags: ios, xcode4

I am putting the finishing touches on my app and for some reason the values are not being shown as a decimal value.

```
if ( row == 0 ) {

    float number1 = ([initamount.text floatValue ]);
    initamount.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%2.f Yard", number1];
    double answer = number1 *3;
    result.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%2.f Feet", answer];

}
```

here is the code i am really tired and could be missing something.

Answer (score 5):

Correct format string should be (note that desired precision should come after '.' in format specifier)

```
@"%.2f Yard"
```

Comment: "The format specifiers supported by [...] NSString [...] and CFString formatting functions follow the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)"